# django channels does not work with more than 20-40 users in one channel

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, daphne

My system: django == 1.11.22, cchannels == 2.1.7, channels-redis == 2.2.1, daphne == 2.2.0, asgiref == 2.3.2

I tried using django pipes to include websockets in my project. The web socket subsystem simply sends system status to administrators and allows messages to be exchanged. My channel layer settings:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        # 'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [(DJANGO_REDIS_HOST, DJANGO_REDIS_PORT)],
            "capacity": 100000,  # default 100
            "expiry": 5  # default 60
        },
    },
}
```

I have increased the capacity of the channels to 100000 messages, but after 20-40 connections to the same URL "/ws/admins/" (this is one group "admins"), I start to get disconnects and duplicate messages, and django on the prod server will stop taking all connections until restarting docker containers. Decreasing expiry does not help either.
if i use InMemoryChannelLayer then there are no errors. The server is started by the command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 web_server.asgi: application

Answer (score 2):

I updated project to Django==2.2.24, channels==2.4.0, channels-redis==3.2.0, daphne==2.5.0, asgiref==3.3.4 and the problem was fixed.